# Get Column Name from table where value is zero

Tags: mysql

I have a query which returns this data back from lets say DefaultersTable

```
Select CustomerID, RoleID FROM DefaultersTable Where DefaulterValue = 1

CustomerID, RoleID
  10034        34
  15481        37
```

Now I have got another Table "DefaultersDetails" which have individual monthly values of them,

so I do

```
Select * from DefaultersDetails Where CustomerID = 10034 AND RoleID = 34.
```

and get the data

```
CustomerID, RoleID, ValueForJan, ValueForFeb, ValueforMar
  10034         34        45          0           32
```

Please note that I got this Entry in the first case only because one of the Value was 0.

Now How Can I get both the data in single Query, I want something like this

```
CustomerID, RoleID, ZeroValueForMonth 
  10034        34       ValueForFeb
  15481        37       ValueForJan
```

I guess it can be done via temprory Tables but I am not sure how to do this

Comment: What if a customer, role combination has zero values for more than one month?

Comment: In that case, there should be 2 entries, one each for month having 0 values

Answer (score 0):

You can use `COALESCE` function. Try this :

```
SELECT d.CustomerID, d.RoleID, 
COALESCE(detail.JAN,detail.FEB,detail.MAR) AS ZeroValueForMonth
FROM DefaultersTable d
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT CustomerID, RoleID,
    (CASE WHEN ValueForJan <> 0 THEN NULL ELSE 'ValueForJan' END) JAN,
    (CASE WHEN ValueForFeb <> 0 THEN NULL ELSE 'ValueForFeb' END) FEB,
    (CASE WHEN ValueForMar <> 0 THEN NULL ELSE 'ValueForMar' END) MAR
FROM Defaultersdetail
) AS detail
ON detail.CustomerID = d.CustomerID AND detail.RoleID = d.RoleId
where d.DefaulterValue = 1
```

You can add other month like MAY, JUN etc on subquery like this :

`(CASE WHEN ValueForApr <> 0 THEN NULL ELSE 'ValueForApr' END) APR`

Comment: I get this Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'detail.CustomerID' in 'on clause'

Comment: Is your table named `DefaultersDetails` has a column named `CustomerID`? because in your question, you wrote this query `Select * from DefaultersDetails Where CustomerID = 10034 AND RoleID = 34` which mean column `CustomerID` exist on your table.

Comment: And make sure you add `SELECT CutomerID,RoleID` on detail subquery.